# Application Loader reports missing code-signing certificate

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog, application-loader

```
I am developing my App in xamarin studio. I want the solution for xamarin Ios app not on xcode.
I produce screenshots about my issue.please give me the right solution.
```

[image]

[image]

[image: When i run my app in Distributing profile getting below error and run on Developer profile deploying successfully on Device.]

[image]

[I am creating Distribution profile like below:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVtQX.png)

[image]

[image]

[image: From Above step it will goes to the generate profile page so Where can i add the device to creating distributing profile:]

[image]

```
And finally Signing Identity is in Developer(Automatic),everything will be fine and app deploying on device but when uploading to the application loader i am getting below error:
```

[image]

```
Signing Identity is in Developer(Automatic) then i am getting the below error:
```

[image]

```
How Can I Solve This?Please help me.
```

Comment: Are you using a Distribution Provisioning Profile?

Comment: yes,but how can i use distribution provisioning profile in my project.

Comment: To Submit to Appstore, you need Appstore profile. Create it in the developer portal, which only allows only to submit the builds to App Store.

Comment: in project options, under "iOS Bundle Signing", you need to be sure that the distribution profile is selected for the build configuration that you are submitting.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing_to_the_app_store/